# How to get total number of rows on a block of a view

Tags: views, 8, blocks

On `hook_block_view_alter()` I need to get a total number of rows that this block displays.

For example, I have a view with the following block:

[image]

On `hook_block_view_alter()` I do the appropriate checks in order to weed out unnecessary blocks and get the one shown in the figure above.

```
function mymodule_block_view_alter(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) {
  if (!preg_match('~^views_block:taxonomy_tag_list~', $block->getPluginId())) {
    return;
  }

  $view = $block->getViewExecutable();
  // Gets the number of rows
  $totalRows = $view->get_total_rows;
}
```

But for some reason, `$totalRows` contains `NULL`.[image]

Here is the object of the current view:
[image]

Why can't I get the total number of rows? Maybe I'm using the wrong hook?

Comment: just curious, why you don't use HEADER (add) in this views display - you can select there "Result summary" with default content "Displaying **start** - **end** of **total**", plus many other tokens related to the current views, and replace with what you want (bold here should be prepended with @ sign but editor here recognize the sign as reference to a user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `views_view_` hook, i.e. `views_view_unformatted`,  `views_view_list`  etc... I tried this with a PHP count for my views block and it worked great.

[image]

My function is:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$vars) {
  $num_rows = $vars["rows"];
  $count = count($num_rows);
  echo '<h2>This view has ' . $count . ' rows</h2><br>';
}
```

This yielded the number of rows in the view.

Printed, I see:

[image]

Comment: I think no need to loop over `$num_rows` just use `count` function like `$count = count($num_rows); `

Comment: @berramou Good idea, answer tested and updated.

Answer (score 2):

No need for any hook.

Adding `{{ view.total_rows }}` in any views template, eg `views-view.html.twig` is enough

Answer (score 1):

No need for any coding. Edit the view and under "Header" or "Footer" add a "Text area" (Category: Global) and see the available global token replacements.

To get the total number of rows add: `[view:total-rows]` and save the view.

Comment: You're right, it's very simple with the token. But the limit is that we cannot make conditions. I needed it to handle the singular/plural of the text displayed after the counter.